# How to link two Fortran files

Tags: fortran

I am very new to Fortran and want to ask how can I run a main program in one Fortran file from another Fortran file.

For instance, I have two Fortran files: `a.for` and `b.for`, Inside `a.for`, there is a main program called `xx`:

```
program xx
....
....
end program xx
```

Inside `b.for`, there is a main program called `yy`:

```
program yy
....
(Call the main program xx from a.for)
....
end program yy
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Until Fortran 2008 the language didn't provide a standard mechanism for calling one program from another; the latest standard introduces a new intrinsic procedure `execute_command_line`.   Not all current compiler (versions) have implemented this feature yet.

However most Fortran compilers (of any vintage) have provided a non-standard way to call one program from another.  To find out if yours does, consult the documentation.  It's immaterial, at this point, whether the called program is written in Fortran or not.

Since you're new to Fortran consider also:

- structuring your computation as a single `program` making use of one, or more, `modules`;
- giving your source files the suffix `f90` which will tell most compilers that you are using free form Fortran rather than the archaic fixed-form; most compilers will assume that `.for` indicates fixed-format Fortran.